# Getting error Dropzone already attached with angular Directives

Tags: javascript, angularjs, dropzone.js

I am using following code for drop zone but i am getting error, i tried to debug it but i am not able to resolve this action plz guide

**http://jsfiddle.net/anam123/rL6Bh/**

```
 -------------------> "Error: Dropzone already attached.

  throw new Error("Dropzone already attached.");"
```

Code::

https://gist.github.com/compact/8118670

snippts:

```
 /**
 * An AngularJS directive for Dropzone.js, http://www.dropzonejs.com/
 * 
 * Usage:
 * 
 * <div ng-app="app" ng-controller="SomeCtrl">
 *   <button dropzone="dropzoneConfig">
 *     Drag and drop files here or click to upload
 *   </button>
 * </div>
 */

angular.module('dropzone', []).directive('dropzone', function () {
  return function (scope, element, attrs) {
    var config, dropzone;

    config = scope[attrs.dropzone];

    // create a Dropzone for the element with the given options
    dropzone = new Dropzone(element[0], config.options);

    // bind the given event handlers
    _.each(config.eventHandlers, function (handler, event) {
      dropzone.on(event, handler);
    });
  };
});

angular.module('app', ['dropzone']);

angular.module('app').controller('SomeCtrl', function ($scope) {
  $scope.dropzoneConfig = {
    'options': { // passed into the Dropzone constructor
      'url': 'upload.php'
    },
    'eventHandlers': {
      'sending': function (file, xhr, formData) {
      },
      'success': function (file, response) {
      }
    }
  };
});
```

Comment: Dropzone.instances have dropzone attatched instances. You can check them.

Answer (score 22):

Solved issue by using following code setup.

So you can either:

1. Turn off autoDiscover globally like this: `Dropzone.autoDiscover = false;`, or
2. Turn off autoDiscover for specific elements like
    this: `Dropzone.options.myAwesomeDropzone = false;`

Reference:
[FAQ  on dropzone](https://github.com/enyo/dropzone/issues/181)

Comment: I am facing same issue ... I tried `Dropzone.autoDiscover = false;` and the other option too ... but I am getting same error

Comment: I eventually gave up. Just commented out the function in dropzone.js 
            `Dropzone._autoDiscoverFunction = function () {
                if (Dropzone.autoDiscover) {
                    return Dropzone.discover();
                }
            };`

Comment: this should be the correct answer. i have faced a similar issue and putting this function before each dropzone instance solved it.

Answer (score 2):

Nothing worked for me so i went to the dropzone.js file and change the line that throw an error (i think in many versions it's in line 426):

```
if (this.element.dropzone) {
    throw new Error("Dropzone already attached.");
  }
```

so i replace

```
throw new Error("Dropzone already attached.");
```

with

```
return this.element.dropzone;
```

and it is working

Answer (score 1):

```
Dropzone.autoDiscover = false;
$('#bannerupload').dropzone({
    url: "/upload",
    maxFilesize: 100,
    paramName: "file",
    maxThumbnailFilesize: 5,
    init: function() {      
      this.on('success', function(file, json) {       
        jQuery("input#mediaid").val(json);
      });
    }
  });
```

Comment: Not sure why this was down-voted, it worked for me. The Dropzone.autoDiscover = false; was all that was needed before the rest of the code.

Comment: ofcourse this works, i tested and implimented this myself

Comment: @ProgrammerCk - Yeah, who could doubt someone with 16 reputation and improper capitalization and punctuation?

Answer (score 0):

I was facing same issue "Dropzone already attached" because we enabled `myDropzone` object in the script and were trying to enable again.

For example

```
if ($('#upl').attr('class')) {

var myDropzone = new Dropzone("#upl", {init: function () {
```

and again trying to enable it

```
 if (jQuery('#password').attr('save_profile')) {
  var myDropzone = new Dropzone("#upl", {init: function () {
```

with another action.

Please check your code.

Answer (score -1):

Put your create dropzone code inside of a try/catch block

```
try{
 $('.dropzone').dropzone({
    url: '/upload'
  });
}
catch(error){
    console.log("Catching " + error);
}
```